# File sharing between Windows, Linux and Android over network

Tags: windows, opensuse, wifi, android, file-sharing

I have a desktop running Windows 7, a laptop running OpenSUSE 13.1 and an Android 4.1 Tablet, all connected to the same network via a router (the desktop through a LAN cable and the others via WiFi).

What would be the best way to share files over this network seamlessly among all three devices?

I have somewhat managed to share files between my laptop and desktop via Samba, but even there it works sometimes if I'm lucky while at other times Dolphin simply crashes. Also I can only share one folder on Windows for some reason (the user folders).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Google Drive and Github for sharing and backup my configures and files

Answer (score 1):

If you know your devices are always going to be in LAN you might prefer syncing over local network.

At my home I have same combination and so far after trying everything I have found [Bit torrent sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) to be the best possible solution. It's beta right now. But pretty usable

In case I happen not to be in my home network I still can access all the files on my android tablet. Changes are synced automatically whenever the devices can connect to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Theres an app for android called file manager with a feature called "pc file transer". Just input the provided address in your windows or linux browser and you have access over your wifi to all the files on your devices.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is always subjective, so here is a way I have done in the past.

I'm guessing that your desktop is where you want to keep the files. Try to sort out the win7 sharing to make sure it works between your opensuse laptop and win7 desktop.

After that I would use an android app called Ghost Commander by Ghost Squared ( it's free ) Then also install their SMB Plugin for Ghost Commander. If you are familiar with Midnight Commander, this app is like it, for android. Then login to your share and copy files. As far as I know the smb plugin only works inside GC.

If you are willing, try to install opensuse minimal install on an older computer with a large hard drive and then configure a Samba server, to share content. Your win7 machine will have no issues connecting to that. Also laptop will be able to do it no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your budget allows it. A nice NAS, from Synology (my recommended choice), QNAP or Drobo provides easy access over SMB. Each also has Android apps for accessing those files via your LAN as well as externally.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a smb/cifs share on your Linux laptop, you'll be able to connect it on both other devices. On android, file manager applications like "fileManager HD" or "ES FileManager" will be able to open SMB network folders.